# Porque mi datatable se ve sin estilo?

Tags: php, datatables

Estoy construyendo una tabla con la ayuda de la librería de [Datatables](https://datatables.net/) y estoy haciendo uso de PHP, tengo un index en el cual declaro todas las dependencias que estaré usando durante mi desarrollo, el siguiente es el código de mi index:

**index.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libraries/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libraries/css/estilos.css" type="text/css">
    <!--JSSH Se agrega dependencias de Datatables-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libraries/datatables/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libraries/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="libraries/js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libraries/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libraries/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="libraries/img/icon.png" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="cuerpo">
        <div class="dividir menu">
            <div class="centrar-vertical">               
                <img src="libraries/img/logo.jpg" width="200" height="40" alt="Test" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <!--<label class="titulo_portal">Test</label>  -->
            <div class="alinear-derecha centrar-vertical">                
                <button id="logout-btn" class="btn btn-default">Cerrar Sesión</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tablaDatatable">  
            <?php   
                include ('views/FacturasView.php');
            ?>
        
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

El siguiente es la vista en donde estoy construyendo mi tabla hecha en Datatables:

**FacturasView.php**

```
<div>
    <table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-bordered" id="iddatatable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Orden de Compra</td>
                <td>Fecha</td>
                <td>Moneda</td>
                <td>Monto Neto</td>
                <td>Lote</td>
                <td>Configuración</td>
                <td>Estado</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#iddatatable').DataTable();
    } );
</script>
```

Al visualizar mi tabla se ve de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Totalmente plana, sin estilos.

Saben si me hace falta agregar mas dependencias o si estoy haciendo mal el llamado de la vista desde el index.

Comment: Creo que faltan las librerias de Datables:

`https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js`

`https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js`

`https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css`

Me parece que solo tienes el JS y no tienes el CSS

Comment: El CSS de Datatable si lo tengo fíjate en el `HEAD` del Index.php

Comment: No sé si soy yo pero no las veo, tienes las de bootstrap pero no veo las de datables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí puedes ver dos ejemplos, uno cuando no tenemos el CSS de DataTables y otro con el CSS. Me parece que tu error es que estas inportando las librerías incorrectas.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#iddatatable').DataTable();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="cuerpo">
    <div class="dividir menu">
      <div class="centrar-vertical">
      </div>
      <!--<label class="titulo_portal">Test</label>  -->
      <div class="alinear-derecha centrar-vertical">
        <button id="logout-btn" class="btn btn-default">Cerrar Sesión</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tablaDatatable">
      <div>
        <table id="iddatatable">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>Orden de Compra</td>
              <td>Fecha</td>
              <td>Moneda</td>
              <td>Monto Neto</td>
              <td>Lote</td>
              <td>Configuración</td>
              <td>Estado</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>1234</td>
              <td>10/10/2020</td>
              <td>USD</td>
              <td>1000</td>
              <td>123456</td>
              <td>Verdadera</td>
              <td>Pagado</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#iddatatable').DataTable();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="cuerpo">
    <div class="dividir menu">
      <div class="centrar-vertical">
      </div>
      <!--<label class="titulo_portal">Test</label>  -->
      <div class="alinear-derecha centrar-vertical">
        <button id="logout-btn" class="btn btn-default">Cerrar Sesión</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tablaDatatable">
      <div>
        <table id="iddatatable">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>Orden de Compra</td>
              <td>Fecha</td>
              <td>Moneda</td>
              <td>Monto Neto</td>
              <td>Lote</td>
              <td>Configuración</td>
              <td>Estado</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>1234</td>
              <td>10/10/2020</td>
              <td>USD</td>
              <td>1000</td>
              <td>123456</td>
              <td>Verdadera</td>
              <td>Pagado</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```